# Infimum as an outer measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $X$ be a set, $A$ an algebra over $X$ and $\mu$ a finite measure on $A$. For $C \in P(X)$, let $\mu^*(C) = $inf$\{\sum \mu(C_k) | C \subset \cup C_k, C_k \in A\}$.

Why is $\mu^*(C) $ an outer measure?

($\mu(\emptyset) = 0$ is clear.)

Comment: because it is also subadditive, as you can check it

Comment: Well, I don't see the subadditivity :/ Why does it hold true that $\mu( \cup C_i) \leq \sum ( \mu ( C_i ) ) $ ?

Comment: It concerns $\mu^*$, not $\mu$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this answer $\mathcal A$ denotes the algebra.

---

Let $A=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_{n}$.

It is our aim to prove that
$\mu^{*}\left(A\right)\leq\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu^{*}\left(A_{n}\right)$.

If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu^{*}\left(A_{n}\right)=\infty$ then we
are are ready, so let us assume now that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu^{*}\left(A_{n}\right)<\infty$.

Let $\epsilon>0$ and for every $n$ find a countable collection $\mathcal{C}_{n}\subseteq\mathcal{A}$
such that $A_{n}\subseteq\bigcup_{C\in\mathcal{C}_{n}}C$ and $\sum_{C\in\mathcal{C}_{n}}\mu C\leq\mu^{*}\left(A_{n}\right)+\epsilon2^{-n}$.

Now let $\mathcal{C}$ denote the union of the collections $\mathcal{C}_{n}$.

Then $\mathcal{C}$ is countable with $\mathcal{C}\subseteq\mathcal{A}$
and $A\subseteq\bigcup_{C\in\mathcal{C}}C$, so that: $$\mu^{*}A\leq\sum_{C\in\mathcal{C}_{n}}\mu C=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{C\in\mathcal{C}_{n}}\mu C\leq\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\mu^{*}\left(A_{n}\right)+\epsilon2^{-n}\right)=\epsilon+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu^{*}\left(A_{n}\right)$$

This can be done for every $\epsilon>0$ so finally we conclude that:
$$\mu^{*}A\leq\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu^{*}\left(A_{n}\right)$$

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer!
Does it follow that each $C \in \mathcal A $ is $\mu^*$ measurable?

Comment: In my answer it is only proved that $\mu^*$ is $\sigma$-subadditive. So no things are proved yet about algebra $\mathcal A$.

Comment: Ok, so what remains to show in order to prove that each $C \in \mathcal A$ is $\mu^*$-measurable?

Comment: That is a *different* question, so you could post it if you like. Eventually with a link to this question.