# Each element of a sigma algebra is measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $X$ be a set, $\mathcal A$ an algebra on $X$ and $\mu$ a finite additive measure on $\mathcal A$. For $A \in P(X)$, let $\mu^*(A) = $inf$\{\sum \mu(A_k) | A \subset \cup A_k, A_k \in \mathcal A\}$.

Why is every $A \in \mathcal A \ \ \mu^*$-measurable?

This question comes from this one: [Infimum as an outer measure](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3385185/infimum-as-an-outer-measure)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any subset $E$ of $X$ and $E\subseteq\displaystyle\bigcup_{n}E_{n}$, $E_{n}\in\mathcal{A}$, we have
\begin{align*}
\mu^{\ast}(E\cap A)+\mu^{\ast}(E\cap A^{c})&\leq\sum_{n}\mu(E_{n}\cap A)+\mu(E_{n}\cap A^{c})\\
&=\sum_{n}\mu(E_{n}),
\end{align*}
so $\mu^{\ast}(E\cap A)+\mu^{\ast}(E\cap A^{c})\leq\mu^{\ast}(E)$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! One last question: If $\mu$ is a $\sigma$-additive measure on $\mathcal A$, then there exists a measure on $\sigma(A)$ which is the same as $\mu$ on $\mathcal A$. Why is this true?

Comment: Actually what is your definition of measure? Story can be very different if different definition is taken into account.

Comment: We say that for a measure $\mu$, the two properties must hold: 1) $\mu(\emptyset) = 0$ and 2) $\sigma$-additivity.

Comment: Then I think your question is a little weird, given $\mu$ $\sigma$-additive, then it is already a measure by your definition.

Comment: But does it hold true that $\mu = \sigma(\mathcal A)$ ?

Comment: That is not hard, consider the outer measure $\mu^{\ast}$ generated by $\mu$ and put $\sigma(\mathcal{A})$ to be those are measurable $A$ defined by $\mu^{\ast}(E)=\mu^{\ast}(E\cap A)+\mu^{\ast}(E\cap A^{c})$ for any subset $E$.